# Associate a function with a type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, record, typeclass

Suppose you have a serializer/deserializer type class

```
class SerDes a where
    ser :: a -> ByteString
    des :: ByteString -> a
```

and it turns out that it's crucial to have a special helper function for each type `a`, e.g.

```
compress :: ByteString -> ByteString     -- actually varies with the original type
```

I see `compress` as a function that I would like to associate with each `a` that is a `SerDes`. (The word "associate" is probably a bad choice, and the reason why internet searches yield nothing.)

The example is not as contrived as it looks, for example when `decompress` is an optional
feature of the serializer/deserializer. (Yes, the helper could be avoided by augmenting
`ser` with a switch that controls the compression, `ser:: a -> Bool -> ByteString`, or better use a `Config` record. But let's stick with the example.)

One way to do this is a 'dummy' class, a singleton:

```
data For a = For
```

Then this will work:

```
class SerDes a where
    ser      :: a -> ByteString
    des      :: ByteString -> a
    compress :: For a -> ByteString -> ByteString
```

and a `compress` for `a` would be instantiated as

```
compress (For :: For MyType) input = ...
```

Another way, somewhat unusual, would be to stick all the functions in a record.

```
data SerDes a = SerDes { ser      :: a -> ByteString
                       , des      :: ByteString -> a
                       , compress :: ByteString -> ByteString 
                       }
```

Are there any other ways to "associate" the `compress` function with the type `a`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your `For a` type is known as `Proxy a` in the libraries.

```
import Data.Proxy

class SerDes a where
    ser      :: a -> ByteString
    des      :: ByteString -> a
    compress :: Proxy a -> ByteString -> ByteString
```

Sometimes this is generalized to a generic `proxy` type variable.

```
class SerDes a where
    ser      :: a -> ByteString
    des      :: ByteString -> a
    compress :: proxy a -> ByteString -> ByteString
```

---

There is another option, similar to proxies. Instead of forcibly adding `a` to the arguments, one can add `a` to the result type using `Tagged`:

```
import Data.Tagged

class SerDes a where
    ser      :: a -> ByteString
    des      :: ByteString -> a
    compress :: ByteString -> Tagged a ByteString
```

This needs to be used as `unTagged (compress someByteString :: Tagged T ByteString)` to tell the compiler we want the `compress` function for `T`.

---

Personally, I'm not a fan of proxies and tags. They were needed in the past when GHC did not allow another simpler solution, but right now they should no longer be used.

The modern approach is to turn on the harmless extensions `AllowAmbiguousTypes` and `TypeApplications` and simply write your wanted class

```
class SerDes a where
    ser      :: a -> ByteString
    des      :: ByteString -> a
    compress :: ByteString -> ByteString
```

In this approach, instead of calling `compress (Proxy :: Proxy T) someByteString` we will need to use the shorter `compress @T someByteString` where we explicitly "pass the type `a` we want" (`T` in this case), so to select the wanted `compress`.

Full example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes, TypeApplications, OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.ByteString as BS

class SerDes a where
    ser      :: a -> ByteString
    des      :: ByteString -> a
    compress :: ByteString -> ByteString

-- bogus implementation to show everything type checks
instance SerDes Int where
   ser _ = "int"
   des _ = 42
   compress bs = BS.tail bs

-- bogus implementation to show everything type checks
instance SerDes Bool where
   ser _ = "bool"
   des _ = True
   compress bs = bs <> bs

main :: IO ()
main = BS.putStrLn (compress @Int "hello" <> compress @Bool "world")
-- output: elloworldworld
```

Comment: “Personally, I'm not a fan of proxies and tags” – me neither, and I don't really see why you start the answer with them in the first place. I think most would now agree that `TypeApplications` are the way to do this sort of thing in modern Haskell, whereas proxies / tagged values are merely of historical interest. (In fact `Tagged` is probably just obselete, it never was very popular; I used to prefer it over proxies while TypeApplications weren't available, but now I'd never use it anymore. Proxies can be combined with TypeApplications better, simply passing `(Proxy @a)`.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout Interesting. In the past, I thought my preference was a minority one, and that many people still preferred to use proxies. If that changed, I'm glad to hear it :). Anyway, since the OP reinvented proxies with `For a`, I think it's appropriate to start with that. I will edit the last section so to stress that it's the modern solution.

Comment: Well, proxies still are used a lot because of legacy libraries, but I hope this will wane in the future.

Comment: I believe there are still cases where you *must* use a `Proxy` argument instead of a type application, no? The latter is definitely preferable unless you actually run into such cases, or unless you need to support older compiler versions.

Comment: @JonPurdy I seem to remember those cases existed, but can't recall any concrete one. Is that still the case nowadays?

Comment: @chi Consider `data IsCons (xs :: [a]) where IsCons :: IsCons (x : xs)`. For `f :: forall xs. IsCons xs -> Blah`, you need to do `type family UnCons1 (xs :: [a]) :: a where { UnCons1 (x : _) = x }; type family UnCons2 (xs :: [a]) :: [a] where { UnCons2 (_ : xs) = xs }; f IsCons = _blah @(UnCons1 xs) @(UnCons2 xs)`. Compare `data IsCons (xs :: [a]) where IsCons :: Proxy# x -> Proxy# xs -> IsCons (x : xs)`. Also, higher rank ambiguous contexts like `type family F (x :: Type) :: Type; f :: (forall a. F a -> F a) -> ()` are pure pain, but `f :: (forall a. Proxy# a -> F a -> F a) -> ()` works.

Comment: Yeah, I was vaguely recalling some issue I had with an ambiguous higher-rank type as well, where I had to add a proxy to satisfy the typechecker. The `reflection` package also depends on the presence of a `Proxy` argument for `class Reifies` and `reify`, first in order to help get away with not actually requiring any instances for `Reifies`, but also to allow for multiple values—the behaviour is undefined for `class Given`, which is the equivalent without the `Proxy`, if multiple instances are in scope.

Comment: @JonPurdy I think you do need `Proxy` when a function is not member of a type class, e.g. when `des` is used and the result is consumed and not returned.

Comment: @HTNW I see that `f IsCons` is more convenient to use with proxies since we do not have a nice way to "pattern match" on types, so we can not easily access the head & tail of the type list there. Technically, proxies are not needed, but they are more convenient there. OTOH, I can't understand the pain in `f :: (forall a. F a -> F a) -> ()` since one could use something like `f g = undefined (g @Int (undefined :: F Int))` to call `g`, and proxies don't make this easier, AFAICS.

Comment: @chi I meant actually calling `f`. If you try to write `f (\x -> _)` you have nothing that can name `a` in `_`. Honestly, I don't remember finding *any* way to refer to `a` inside the lambda in this context. This becomes *highly* annoying in when working with arbitrary type functions, e.g. through `singleton`'s defunctionalization approach: `data HList (f :: a ~> Type) (xs :: [a]) :: Type where { .. }; mapH :: (forall a. f @@ a -> g @@ a) -> HList f xs -> HList g xs`. Though in this case, we can set either `f, g = TyCon1 Blah` instead of `Proxy#`, but that kind of defeats the point...