# Associate a non-type-class function with a type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass

This is a follow-up question to [Associate a function with a type in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63667281/associate-a-function-with-a-type-in-haskell).

Again, suppose you have a serializer/deserializer type class

```
class SerDes a where
    ser :: a -> ByteString
    des :: ByteString -> a
```

and you want to provide some sanity check or test case that varies with type `a`,

```
check :: ByteString -> Bool
```

Of course `des` is used deep in the guts of `check` but the type `a` can't be deduced. To do
something useful with `a` it probably needs to be member of some type class, let's say it's `Show a`.

As usual, [Proxy](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Proxy.html) can do the job:

```
data Proxy a = Proxy    -- or import Data.Proxy

check :: Proxy a -> ByteString -> Bool
check (Proxy :: Proxy MyType) input = ...      
check (Proxy :: Proxy MyOtherType) input = ...
```

(With the extension `TypeApplications` this can be made more succinct: `check (Proxy @MyType) ...`.)

But can `Proxy` be avoided? (Provided you can't move `check` into the `SerDes` type class.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must first mention that you have a problem in the design of your typeclass. The signature of your `des` function says that for each input `ByteString` there exists a valid output `a`. This is likely not true.

For example, imagine having an instance of `SerDes` for `Int`. By your definition, you'll have a valid `Int` representation even for 6GB `ByteString` of random data. Sounds wrong.

For this reason, you need to specify the possibility of deserialization failures in the signature of `des`. A typical approach would be to wrap `a` in `Maybe` or `Either YourDetailedRepresentationOfFailure`. E.g.,

```
class SerDes a where
  ser :: a -> ByteString
  des :: ByteString -> Either Text a
```

In fact this is the approach essentially taken by all Haskell serialization and parsing libraries. They may introduce some abstractions there, but in essence they all find ways to represent deserialization failures.

Now to your actual question. Typeclass instances are identified by the type they are for, so you must provide the specific type for `a` somehow. `Proxy` is one option for that. Another one is to directly refer to that type without using it in your function and passing in the `undefined` value for it. Third (and cleanest one, IMO) is to wrap the result in [`Tagged`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagged-0.8.6/docs/Data-Tagged.html#t:Tagged).

### The `undefined` option

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, TypeApplications #-}

check :: forall a. SerDes a => a -> ByteString -> Bool
check _ bytes =
  isRight (des @a bytes)
```

*Please notice that `forall` and `ScopedTypeVariables` extension are required to be able to refer to the type parameter in the function def.*

You'll then call this function like this:

```
check (undefined :: a) bytes
```

or this:

```
check @a undefined bytes
```

### The `Tagged` option

```
check :: SerDes a => ByteString -> Tagged a Bool
check bytes =
  fmap isRight (Tagged (des bytes))
```

You'll then call this function like this:

```
unTagged (check @a bytes)
```

### Final note

In reality you'll likely never need the `check` function, since `des` already carries all the information needed and more. It's easier and more understandable to just have `isRight (des @a bytes)` in place where you need `check`. The fact that you have to go thru complications for defining `check` is actually a signal of a design mistake. In practical Haskell code you'll rarely meet such complications.

Comment: Whether the example is well chosen isn't really the question. I think it's clear what I'm getting at, but if you have an example with better semantics than my `SerDes` I'm all ears.

Comment: May I draw your attention to the fact that you're being rude to a person who tried to help you?

Comment: Sorry if my comment came across as rude, that was not the intention.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can specify the type `a` via `TypeApplications` in the exact same way as in the answer you have linked:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, AllowAmbiguousTypes, TypeApplications #-}

check :: forall a. SerDes a => ByteString -> Bool
check bytes = ... des @a bytes ...
```

Note that you need `ScopedTypeVariables` and `forall a.` in order to create a scope for the type variable `a` so that you can refer to it when calling `des`. Without an explicit `forall`, the type variable's scope would be limited to just the type signature and you couldn't mention it in the body.

To call the `check` function, use type application as before:

```
check @Int bytes
```